# How to change JButton text in one class based on data from another class?

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton

Background: I have an AccountingModuleUI `JFrame`, which has a Chart of Accounts `JPanel` that contains account `JButtons` as part of an `ArrayList` as they are generated through a CreateAccount `JButton`, code for continuous Jbutton generation as follows:

```
private void btnCreateAccountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    jLabel2.setText("Chart of Accounts");        
    buttonArrayList.add(new JButton("Button"+buttonCount));
    panelAccounts.add(buttonArrayList.get((buttonArrayList.size()-1)));
    buttonArrayList.get((buttonArrayList.size()-1)).show();
    buttonCount++;
    buttonArrayList.get((buttonArrayList.size()-1)).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        inputForm.show();
        }
    });
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

When one of the newly created JButtons is clicked, the input form is presented, which is it's own stand alone class. The user enters information and clicks the Submit button, which then creates Account objects, through the following code within my InputForm Class:

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    acctName = txtAcctName.getText();
    acctClass = cboxAcctClass.getSelectedItem().toString();
    acctSubClass = cboxAcctSubClass.getSelectedItem().toString();
    acctCCY = cboxAcctCCY.getSelectedItem().toString();
    accountArrayList.add(new Accounts(acctName, acctClass, acctSubClass,(i+1)));
    i++;
    this.hide();
}
```

Everything works up to this point, but I am having difficulty trying to get the acctName of an Account object back to the JButton text in my AccountingModuleUI class starting point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look up Model-View-Controller design architecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

In your case I would have a controller class update your view in response to updates in the model. The functionality of **btnSubmitActionPerformed** can be extended to update the JButton with the new account name.